# Why does raw_input create an infinite loop in this Learn Python the Hard Way exercise variant?

Tags: python, while-loop

I'm trying to work my way through Learn Python the Hard Way, and trying to mess around where I can to further my education. I thought this would work: set up raw_input to set a limit for a while loop, then let the while loop execute to the limit I establish with the variable "frequency".

It, uh, doesn't. Instead, it sends Python into an infinite loop of creating number lists, each seeming to be one increment longer than the last (very long) list.

The original code had "while i < 6" -- I've added the raw_input variable, and even if I enter the same variable as in the original code (6), it does this infinite-loop thing.

Here's the full script:

```
i = 0 
numbers = []

print "What is the frequency?"
frequency = raw_input ('Kenneth? ')

while i < frequency:
    print "At the top i is %d" % i
    numbers.append(i)
    i = i + 1
    print "Numbers now: ", numbers
    print "At the bottom i is %d" % i

print "The numbers: "

for num in numbers: 
    print num
```

Apologies for maximum ignorance -- I've got a copy of Python for Software Design in front of me in paperback right now, and it's the next thing on my to-do list after LPTHW.

Comment: You might find the following useful. It's about how strings and ints are compared in python. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3270680/how-does-python-compare-string-and-int

Comment: try changing `raw_input` to `input`

Comment: or `frequency = int(raw_input ('Kenneth? '))`

Comment: Your comparison is always returning True. You need to convert your raw_input value to an int (int()) to get the desired result. 
Try the following from an interactive shell:

i=6
i<5
i<'5'

And you'll understand what's going on.

Comment: @TomIngram That approach can leave you with an unhandled exception when the user gives a value that can't be cast to an int.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`raw_input` will give you a string object, not an integer. Try to make `frequency = int(frequency)` before the loop, it will make the comparison valuable.

Comment: It would be also more implicit to cast the entire thing as an int before assignment:  `frequency = int(raw_input('Kenneth? '))`.

Comment: Oho! Okay, I get it. The string is returning "true" and therefore all I'm getting is a forever "true" loop and not the pure result I'd get from an integer. Thanks!

Comment: @Makoto only if you handle exceptions. `int(raw_input(…))` throws a `ValueError` if the value given is not int castable.

Comment: @kojiro: Of course.  But even then you'd have to `try...except` even the casting of the int in the standalone variable if we were to go that far. ;)

Comment: @Makoto Or you could test that the value contains a usable string before casting. `if` statements are cheaper than bare error handling.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> 3 < '2'
0: True
```

That's your hint.

Answer (score 1):

Because raw_input results in a string.

```
>>> frequency = "10"
>>> i = 0
>>> while i < frequency:
...     i = i + 1
...     print i
...     if i > 20: break
... 
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
21
```

Answer (score 1):

The number that you entered is a string rather than a integer

Just add `frequency = int(frequency)` before the while loop